# Get resolved file name from Rollup

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

I setup a new project today using Vite/Rollup for the first time. I understand that Rollup will automatically scan your JS and (with the right plugins) HTML, etc files to magically find any referenced assets/entries and replace them with their production URLs when building.

E.g.

```
import { something } from './src/module.js';
```

Might turn into

```
import { something } from '/assets/js/module-<hash>.js';
```

Now let's say I have a not further specified use-case where I want to get the URL to module.js bundle/file in production to do something with it that Rollup can't automagically resolve for me. How would I go about this?

E.g.

```
const url = rollupResolve('./src/module.js');
doSomethingWithUrl(url);
```

I've searched the documentation and the internet for the last couple hours but didn't find anything that actually worked. In fact, I wasn't even able to find anyone asking this specific question.

The closest to this I found was to use `new URL('./src/module.js', import.meta.url).href`, but this -- at least with default settings -- will give me an inlined version of the file if it is small enough and there doens't seem to be a way to override that behavior on a per-callsite basis or even just for that one specific file.

Any input or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate more on "a note specified use-case" situation? It is not clear from the question.

Comment: @HarshalPatil: It says "a not further specified use-case", i.e. "I am explicitly not sharing my use-case with you". For the purpose of this question my question is "How do I get the filenames of transformed and chunked packages and assets to do something with in my application code?".  What I am intending on doing with them I don't think is really helpful to know and I am afraid could derail the conversation into a direction I don't want it to go (e.g. "Just use this fully featured plugin that will do all these things for you").

Comment: That said, I did find [a plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-output-manifest) that will generate a manifest file which will list out all the entry points and assets and their respective transformed packages. It requires me to do a round-trip to fetch the manifest, instead of inlining it into my application directly, but that is something I can live with for now and can optimize moving forward.

Comment: Perfect. That's what you are then looking for. On a sidenote, you can use the programmatic API to retrieve this information! And, also, if you end up using Vite eventually, you will get this manifest generated out of the box.

Comment: @HarshalPatil Mind elaborating a little on the two points of using the programmatic API as well as Vite generating this manifest out of the box? Both sound very interesting to me and I didn't come across either of them while looking for a solution.

Comment: Here's the relevant documentation explaining how to enable Vite manifest generation: https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [output manifest plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-output-manifest) which generates a manifest of all the processed Rollup output files (i.e. entry points and assets).

While it is a standalone file that requires an additional round trip to be able to utilize this list in the application code (instead of inlining it), that is acceptable for the time being and something that can be optimized down the line.